# Receiving comment deprecated error when attempting to loop through the results of a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, deprecated

I am trying to loop through the results of a MySQL query via PHP. My code is below.

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proxies"));

for($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i++) {

  echo $list['address'];

}
```

This results in: "PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0". However, when I try this...

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proxies"));

for($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i++) {

  echo $list['id'];

}
```

it works. So something must be wrong with the database column? Also, I went in `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini` and changed the `#` comment to `//` and retried running my script. It showed no results and gave no errors.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't comment out some code that needed to be run?

Comment: your code is seems to be fine

Comment: except for the deprecated `mysql_*` calls

Comment: @Fluffeh Yes, I am sure. There are only 2 lines of code in `ming.ini` and one of them is the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Found this...

http://www.howtoforge.com/debian-squeeze-apache2-php5-php-deprecated-comments-starting-with-are-deprecated-in-etc-php5-apache2-conf.d-ming.ini-on

and this....

http://pravams.com/2011/08/18/php-deprecated-comments-starting-with-are-deprecated/

try removing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change all comments starting with `#` from this:

```
# comment here
```

to `//`:

```
// comment here
```

Comment: @flowers In all of the files? (That page, the `.ini` file, and any other files that are `include`d?)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from one of the links in @Klemorali's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Note:Your code is deprecated with the mysql* codes.

You need to go into /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini and change those # to ; An article I just read said this.

Answer (score 0):

Comment issue is not in your code issue in in php.ini or ming.ini use ; instead of #